# libudev to filter unnecessary output with NULL value

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, udev

By having this snippet in my code,

```
UsbInfo = udev_device_get_sysattr_value(device,"idProduct");
printf("\n====product ID: %s\n", UsbInfo);
```

with the output like the following:

```
====product ID: c52b

====product ID: (null)

====product ID: (null)

====product ID: (null)

====product ID: (null)

====product ID: (null)
```

This is reasonable because only one path contains idProduct file and other paths dont.

However, is there any approach can filter these null value and only print out the one I need ?

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: i know a possibility is to use "if" to check the returned value.
However, I would like to know if there is any other functions provided  naturally.

Comment: What is unnatural about `if`?

Comment: well, it will check a bunch of null return since libudev will enumerate all directories. I think there might be some better ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, afaik,
libudev does not support the filter function to this.

So I took the "if" conditional loop to filter out the message I need.